# How to clean up Zookeeper cluster configuration?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I set up zookeeper cluster with 3 nodes successfully. How can I clean up existing cluster configuration and how to do these nodes like a standalone?

Answer (score 0):

Found way:

1) need to edit zoo.cfg config file, particularly comment 
setting servers part:

```
dataDir=/var/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
#server.1=zookeeper1:2888:3888
#server.2=zookeeper2:2888:3888
#server.3=zookeeper3:2888:3888
```

2) remove snaps in data dir in my case is:

```
rm -rf /var/zookeeper/version-2/*
```

3) restart zookeeper server:

```
zkServer.sh restart
```

Need to execute on each node.